# Finding the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+1/2+1/3+\ldots+1/n}{(\pi^{n}+e^{n})^{1/n}\ln n}$

Tags: limits

Find the given limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+1/2+1/3+\ldots+1/n}{(\pi^{n}+e^{n})^{1/n}\ln n}$$

I'm able to find one part in denominator of this limit i.e. $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\pi ^{n} + e^{n})^{1/n} = \pi$ 
So there will be a $\pi$ in the denominator of the answer. How to find the rest part$?$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n \sim \gamma+\ln n$, where $\gamma=0.577\ldots$, is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.
So your limit becomes
$$
L
=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln n+\gamma}{\pi \ln n}
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\pi}+ \frac{\gamma}{\pi\ln n} \right)
=\frac{1}{\pi}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n := \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$.
Since $b_n := \sqrt[n]{\pi^n + e^n} \ln(n)$ is a strictly monotone sequence diverging to $\infty$, by the theorem of [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_%E2%88%99/%E2%88%9E_case) we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n + 1} - a_{n}}{b_{n + 1} - b_{n}} \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(n + 1) \big[ \sqrt[n + 1]{\pi^{n + 1} + e^{n + 1}} \ln(n+1) - \sqrt[n]{\pi^{n} + e^{n}} \ln(n)\big]}
= \frac{1}{\pi}
\end{align}
To see this we show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(n + 1) \left[\left(1 + \left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^{n + 1}\right)^{\frac{1}{n + 1}} \ln(n+1) - \left( 1 + \left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \ln(n)\right]}
= 1.
$$
This follows from the $\left( 1 + \left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 1$ (thanks to op for pointing that out) and $$(n + 1)( \ln(n + 1) - \ln(n) ) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 1.$$